# driver.get can't locate the chromdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

my python code.

```
DRIVER_PATH = 'D:/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options , executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
```

please note that my python file and chrome driver are located in the same folder. but still my code generates an error as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\anaconda\envs\AHG_web\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "E:\anaconda\envs\AHG_web\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "E:\anaconda\envs\AHG_web\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrapper_new_EIB.py", line 25, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options , executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
  File "E:\anaconda\envs\AHG_web\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "E:\anaconda\envs\AHG_web\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

despite the above code, I also added chromedriver.exe to the environment variable as well. and again I get the same error.  how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

If the `chromedriver` is in the same path as your `python` script, then there is no need to specify the full path. You can simply specify `chromedriver.exe`. Plus, it is advisable to specify the parameters for `webdriver.Chrome` in this order: `executable_path, options`. Thus, this is how your final code should look like:

```
DRIVER_PATH = 'chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH, options=options)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the driver and your script are in the same directory you can use a relative path to your chromedriver like this:

```
DRIVER_PATH = './chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options , executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
```